# Change App Name in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

guy's there is a problem with android studio.I make a splash screen in Manifest then I run the app in emulator the app name is splash.see the screnshot.
[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4HA6.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty1fT.png)

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Times Table</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_splash">Splash</string>
</resources>
```

need help.

Comment: Post your String.xml file

Comment: Reinstall your app once

Answer (score 18):

go to your  values/strings.xml and change this

```
<string name="app_name">Splash</string>
```

to

```
<string name="app_name">YourName</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to check 2 things here

1. Your Android Mainifest show have something like this

   ```
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

and navigate to Strings under Values, ensure you find this line inside your code

```
<string name="app_name">Your App Name HERE</string>
```

So the String you are referencing to is "app_name"

Comment: So the App Label from you android navigation is declared in your Android Manifest <application>
 android:label="@string/app_name"
</application>

Comment: Had the same problem and this worked,its so simple i just uninstalled and installed the app to apply the changes.

Answer (score 3):

you can change your name form string.xml

like this

```
<string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

What it takes is your launcher activities label. Hence go to your manifest check its label and change it to whatever you want.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourStartActivity"
        android:label="@string/your_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Create your_name string in strings.xml . Should work . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of your app by making changes in your strings.xml,

`<string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>`
And make sure that it is linked to the `label` attribute of `application` tag in your `manifest` file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the title of the LAUNCHER activity, in your case the SplashActivity, so put he title you want int the title_activity_splash resource.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the value of `android:label="appname"` inside the `<application>` in the manifest page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the res folder > values > strings. xml and change the app_name to your new name. Done!